# Nginx virtual host not working (wrong redirect)

Tags: nginx

i'm new to nginx and i have a problem with virtual host. The virtual host didn't work when i try to access the vhost it'll be redirect to localhost "Welcome to nginx". Here are the contents of my config:

**/etc/hosts** config:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain

::1 localhost localhost.localdomain

****Generated by Admin****

18.200.10.50 mail.testingweb.com

18.200.10.50 testingweb.com
```

SSL config on **/etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl.conf:**

```
server {
       listen 443 default_server ssl;
       server_name testingweb.com;

       ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/sslcert/xxxx.crt;
       ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/sslcert/xxxxx.key;

       ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
       ssl_session_timeout 10m;
       keepalive_timeout 70;

       ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
       ssl_ciphers "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA RC4 !aNU$
       ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

       location / {
               root /usr/share/nginx/html;
               index index.php index.html index.htm;
       }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;

                # With php5-fpm:
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

}
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/default** config:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        # listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        root /usr/share/nginx/xhtml;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;


        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name testingweb.com;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
        error_page 404 /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;

        #       # With php5-fpm:
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }


        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443;
        return 403;
}
```

I want to access another sites from new root directory, **/usr/share/nginx/html/www** on www directory there is a **wordpress**.

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/testingweb** config:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        # listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html/www;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;


        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name testingweb.com;

#       rewrite ^ https://$http_host$request_uri? permanent;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
                # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
                # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules;
        }


   error_page 404 /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;

        #       # With php5-fpm:
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

#       location = /favicon.ico {
#               alias /usr/share/nginx/html/favicon.ico;
#       }


        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

According the configs, what's wrong with my config ? i cannot access the wordpress file on **/usr/share/nginx/html/www** directory by domain **testingweb.com** ? its always redirect to **default** host instead of **testingweb** host ?

sorry for my bad english..

Comment: Both your ``default`` and ``testingweb`` configurations are returning 301 redirects in the middle of the block, before even proxying requests to php-fpm. Is your nginx working at all?

Comment: Yes, the server (nginx) is working fine. So should i remove the returning 301 on 'testingweb' ?

Comment: You only need the return directive if you need to redirect a request to another URL -- so if you want the requests that end up in your default server block to go to ``testingweb`` where your WordPress setup is, then keep the return in the default config. But you don't need it in ``testingweb`` if you have rules (location blocks) to handle the request.

Comment: is your ``testingweb`` configuration working OK for your WordPress site?

Comment: @kchan ok, i'll try it later. 

yes, i can access Wordpress sites over testingweb.com/www instead of testingweb.com

Comment: well @kchan this is my new config http://pastebin.com/rtwEJKrE 
i removed conf.d/ssl.conf and site-available/default, just used that config, but still doesn't work ?

Comment: What exactly is not working? Cqn you explain what you're aiming for and what is the result you're getting right now that is incorrect?

Comment: Please post info about where exactly your website's root directory is (your configurations have different locations or are missing the ``root`` directive so nginx may not be using the correct directory). Also, are you using port 80 to serve your site or are you using 443? Or is 80 supposed to redirect to 443?

Comment: the vhost is not working (from **(https)://testingweb.com/www** to **(https)://testingweb.com**), my website directory is in **/var/www** and i supposed to redirect port 80 to port 443..

Comment: Please see the code I posted and test to see if this works for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a revised version of the nginx configuration from your pastebin code:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        # listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
        # Make site accessible from http://devdev.com/
        server_name devdev.com;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri; 
}

# HTTPS server
#
server {
        listen 443 default_server ssl;
        server_name devdev.com;
        root /var/www;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        # uncomment to add your access log path here
        # access_log /var/log/nginx/devdev.com.access.log main;

        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/ssl-unified.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/ssl-my-private-decrypted.key;

        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_timeout 10m;
        keepalive_timeout 70;

        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS +RC4 RC4";
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

        location @default {
                rewrite ^/(.*) /index.php?uri=$request_uri last;
        }

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/index.php @default;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;

                # With php5-fpm:
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

}
```

The first server block listening on port 80 just redirects to `https://devdev.com/`. This will redirect all `http` requests to `https` so you don't need any other processing rules.

The second server block listens on port 443 and will proxy requests with a path ending with `.php` to `php-fpm` (you want to double-check that it's running on a unix socket and your permissions are correct).

The location block matching the `/` prefix (`location /`) will try to match files in the request URI and handle the request appropriately. For example:

- If the request is for `/index.php` and the file exists, the following block will match the `.php` suffix and proxy to `php-fpm`.
- If the request is for `/foo` and there's no match for a file by that name, nginx will try to match `/foo/index.php` and then proxy to `php-fpm`.
- If there is still no match, `try_files` will use the `@default` location block, which just sends the request to your top-level `/index.php` with the request URI as parameters.

If your WordPress site is located in `/var/www` -- the top-level entry point should be `/var/www/index.php` -- this configuration should work. You might need to tweak the configurations based on your WordPress settings -- though this is generic enough that it should work without a lot of changes.

Comment: thanks for the config, but its still didn't work, when i access (http://)devdev.com its always redirect to **index.html** from **/usr/share/nginx/html**..

Comment: The problem was solved. Its caused by wrong `location / { .. }` in SSL server block. Thank you so much for your help @kchan